# Windows batch file with TYPE command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have 10 files like below:

- `file1.txt` (file content = "i contain text for file1")
- `file2.txt` (file content = "i contain text for file2")
- `file3.txt` (file content = "i contain text for file3")

and so

---

I am trying to do a `TYPE` command like:

```
type file*.txt > OUTPUT.txt
```

this works to output the file contents only. i need output to also have filename for each file.

my `output.txt` file should look like this:

```
file1.txt = "i contain text for file1"
file2.txt = "i contain text for file2"
file3.txt = "i contain text for file3"
```

Comment: `findstr "^" "file*.txt"`

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ. this was so simple and works exactly the way i want.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file called proc.bat which contains:

```
echo %1=>>output.txt
type %1>>output.txt
```

Then use this command:

```
for %v in (file*.txt) do proc %v
```

Answer (score 2):

Use next command from `cmd` window:

```
>output.txt (for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %G in ('findstr "^" "file*.txt"') do @echo %G = "%H")
```

If used in a batch script, double percent signs in `for` loop inner variables (i.e. `%%G`, `%%H` instead of `%G`, `%H` respectively):

```
@echo off
>output.txt (for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('findstr "^" "file*.txt"') do echo %%G = "%%H")
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>` special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for /l %f in (1,1,3) do echo|set /p="File %f = " >> output.txt & type file%f.txt >> output.txt
```

This will yield a file that looks like:

```
File 1 = Text in file1
File 2 = Text in file2
File 3 = Text in file3
```

The `for /l` command counts from 1 to 3 in increments. In general `(start,increment,end)`.